# How to adjust labels with ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to augment my dataset with Keras's [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator) for use with [model.fit_generator()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods).  I see I can randomly flip images.  For flipped images, I need to modify the corresponding label.  How can I do that?

EDIT: I'm doing regression, not classification, so if an image is flipped I need to adjust the label.  The actual images are from a self-driving car simulator, and the labels are the steering angles.  If I horizontally flip an image, I need to negate the steering angle.

Comment: Are interested in a hack solution?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Of course!

Comment: What is your dim_ordering?

Comment: `dim_ordering='tf'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
import numpy

def fliping_gen(image_generator, flip_p=0.5):
    for x, y in image_generator:
        flip_selector = numpy.random.binomial(1, flip_p, size=x.shape[0]) == 1
        x[flip_selector,:,:,:] = x[flip_selector,:,::-1,:]
        y[flip_selector] = (-1) * y[flip_selector]
        yield x, y
```